# Creating a date and time column from datetime column in mysql

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to extract date and time to seperate columns from a datetime column in mysql. I have looked around and its possible to do the exact opposite. So is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Show your actual query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [date and time functions of MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html) come in handy:

```
SELECT DATE(yourDatetimeColumn), TIME(yourDatetimeColumn) FROM yourTable;
```

For the details you should look at [DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) and [TIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) in the manual.

With [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) you get the right data type for the computed columns:

```
SELECT
    STR_TO_DATE(DATE(yourDatetimeColumn), '%Y-%m-%d') As yourDate,
    STR_TO_DATE(TIME(yourDatetimeColumn), '%k:%i') As yourTime
FROM
    yourTable;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it worked like a charm. Thanks, I am not very good with mysql and i am regretting not learning it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You use `DAY()`, `HOUR`,`Minute` functions accordingly. See [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

An example would be like

```
select DAY(NOW()) , hour(NOW())
```